# rworldmap: plot two maps using the same palette

Tags: r, plot, r-maptools, rworldmap

I want to plot two different Eurasian maps using the same palette. My dataframe is like:

> head(df)

d1   d2 country

1 4.4 14.2     ALB

2 2.9  5.2     AND

3 9.9 36.9     ARM

4 5.6 69.0     AZE

5 2.9  7.3     AUT

6 8.1  9.3     BEL

so on..

**for map1:**

> map1<- joinCountryData2Map(df, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "country")
> mapCountryData(map1, nameColumnToPlot = "d1", catMethod = "pretty", mapRegion = "Eurasia", colourPalette = "white2Black", missingCountryCol = "white")

[map1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAyTu.jpg)

**for map2:**

> map2<- joinCountryData2Map(df, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "country")
> mapCountryData(map2, nameColumnToPlot = "d2", catMethod = "pretty", mapRegion = "Eurasia", colourPalette = "white2Black", missingCountryCol = "white")

[map2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7Dlr.jpg)

I want both map1 and map2 share the same palette (In this argument the palette in map2 is suitable because it has bigger values and it contains palette in map1). e.g "ARM" will be darker in map2 (36.9>9.9) with the same palette scales.

Is that possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and the code you've tried so far that doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Done; edited with an example

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok; `catMethod` is the answer:

```
catMethod = c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140)
```

The same `catMethod` in the map1 and map2 gave what I want.

Asking questions is the beginning of the answers.

Comment: You are encouraged to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)